# React: REST redirect failing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

There is a textfield which has an event handler to submit when **[Enter Key]** is pressed.

```js
const [ query, setQuery ] = React.useState('')
...
<TextField 
      label="Search Codebase"  
      id="queryField"
      onChange={ event => setQuery(event.target.value)}
      onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
   />
```

This is the key down handler function

```js
  const handleKeyDown = e  => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      console.log('moving to: /search/' + query); // query here = `TextField value`
      window.location.href = '/search/' + query;  // query here = '?'
    }
  }
```

Resultant URL is => ***/search/?***
URL should be    => ***/search/contents of TextField***

Comment: What happens if you cut out local state and just pass the event directly to your onKeyDown?

Comment: so you want to redirect it on `handleKeyDown` with the content of `query` attached at the end  of `/search/` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `history` object from `react-router-dom`, and redirect with query params, like this:

```
  import React, { Fragment, useState} from "react";
  import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

  const history = useHistory();

  const handleKeyDown = e  => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      console.log('moving to: /search/' + query); // query here = `TextField value`
      history.push({
        pathname: '/search',
        search: query // Should be of the form `?${param}=${value}`
      })
    }
  }
```

Read more about the history object [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/history.md).

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Redirect` from `react-router-dom` ,so what you want to do is create a state variable `redirect` and Redirect based on the state variable.

```
   import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
   import React, { Fragment, useState} from "react";

  const [ redirect, setRedirect ] = useState(false)    

  const handleKeyDown = e  => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      console.log('moving to: /search/' + query); // query here = `TextField value`
     setRedirect(true)
    }
  }
```

and in the `return` of your component you would do

```
return (
{redirect && (<Fragment>
<Redirect to=`/search/${query}` />
</Fragment>)}
//Rest of Code
```

Hope This Helps

Comment: ```return <Redirect to=`/search/${query}` />;``` generates an error

Comment: Parsing error: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text - and it is pointing to the first backtick ` - right after `to=`

Comment: try ```<Redirect to={`/search/${query}`} />```

Comment: @Michael err now reads: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions.  I am understanding through this process how Redirect works but something is not quite there yet.